# Grassman algebra and Maxima

Tags: reference-request, geometric-algebras, maxima-software

How can I setup the Maxima atensor package for manipulating Grassman algebra ?

The [documentation](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_27.html) just mentions a grassman option for initializing the atensor package (init_atensor).

I can't find any relevant example or tutorial.

Thanks

PS : Feel free to share about other free software alternatives. Maybe choosing Maxima for this task is bad.

Comment: Did anyone already use Maxima for solving any geometric algebra problems ?

Comment: Python has a Grassman algebra module called clifford that you might find useful.